# How to override payment.xml file from module-payment

Tags: magento2

How to override following xml file `vendor/magento/module-payment/etc/payment.xml` in magento 2.x

Comment: Please take a reference paypal module.

Answer (score 2):

My requirement was to change  "Discover" Credit card text to "Discover Card"

Steps To Override payment.xml

1. create a "payment.xml" inside etc and add the following code to change the text.

   ```
   <payment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Payment:etc/payment.xsd">
     <credit_cards>
          <type id="DI" order="30">
            <label>Discover Card</label>
          </type>
     </credit_cards>
   </payment>
   ```

Comment: Hi @Renu
Can we override another options as well ?
Like canUseInternal or canUseCheckout etc. ?

Comment: @ParthThakkar I haven't seen such canUseInternal text in payment.xml file. Could you please elaborate a bit what exactly you want to achieve